# Fields with the same name across different anonymous unions inside one union

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, unions, type-definition

Is it legal to have fields with the same name across different anonymous unions inside one union?

```
union Foo
{
    union
    {
        int bar;
    };

    union
    {
        int bar;
    };
};
```

This code fails to compile by GCC but works fine in MSVC.

Comment: It looks like this is not allowed: "Members of an anonymous union are injected in the enclosing scope (and must not conflict with other names declared there)" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#Anonymous_unions

Comment: It is a language extension of `cl`. Disable language extensions (`/Za`) and happily get: `error C2658: 'Foo::bar': redefinition in anonymous struct/union`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not allowed by C++ standard. Any compiler which compiles this code is non-conformant.

See 10.4.1/1:

> The names of the members of an anonymous union shall be distinct from
>   the names of any other entity in the scope in which the anonymous
>   union is declared.